# sql-injection urls, is length of a parameter a security issue?

Tags: php, sql-injection, parameter-passing

I'm getting a lot of hits that involve sql injection attempts that involve increasingly long  parameters.  I am limiting the parameters in php to cast them as positive ints or zero, but I'm not certain that there isn't some kind of trick involving really long parameters that could cause me problems (buffer overflow problems?).

I know that the suhosin patch in php has some kind of patching of excessively long parameters, though I don't have that in place currently.  What should I do to protect myself against cases like this (from my logs)?

```
ProductId=47&ItemId=-1025+UNION+SELECT+0x6d6567613164756d706572,0x6d6567613264756d706572,0x6d6567613364756d706572,0x6d6567613464756d706572,0x6d6567613564756d706572,0x6d6567613664756d706572,0x6d6567613764756d706572,0x6d6567613864756d706572,0x6d6567613964756d706572,0x6d65676131064756d706572,0x6d65676131164756d706572,0x6d65676131264756d706572,0x6d65676131364756d706572,0x6d65676131464756d706572,0x6d65676131564756d706572,0x6d65676131664756d706572,0x6d65676131764756d706572,0x6d65676131864756d706572,0x6d65676131964756d706572,0x6d65676132064756d706572,0x6d65676132164756--
```

Comment: The only issue I can think of is a truly insanely large field value causing your query to exceed the DB protocol's maximum packet size. MySQL, for one, can't split queries a cross multiple packets.

Comment: What would you expect the outcome to be, kinda a denial of service result in that it would slow down the system?  I plan to add the suhosin patch, but I have to work out all the secondary effects it will have.

Comment: I'm guessing a syntax error, since things would get chopped off mid-data, kinda like `INSERT INTO table (....) VAL[chop]`.

Comment: You might want to search google for strings like `0x6d6567613164756d706572` or the equivilent string conversion `mega1dumper`.  Hopefully you won't find your own website in the search results.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to validate the user input. It will return the input as an integer or a 0 if parsing fails. The latter would be the case in your example.

```
$filteredItemId = intval($_GET['itemId']);

if($filteredItemId <= 0) { /* invalid id given */ } else { /* do stuff */ }
```

Comment: yeah, currently I use: `// Return a casting with a result of a positive int, or else zero.
function positive_int($num){
 return ((int)$num == $num && (int)$num > 0? (int)$num : 0);
}` to prevent negative integers as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use prepared statements. The parameters are escaped before send to the database and could not do any damage.

**UPDATE**

The same mechanism could be applied to the rest of user supplied content too.
Use `htmlspecialchars()` to escape all data, you get from the user. This should also be safe to XSS attacks (in most cases)

Comment: Good one, but they don't protect you against XSS attacks.

Comment: right @henchman, but that was not the question ;) Or did i missed something in the text?

Comment: What should I do to protect myself against cases like this (from my logs)? I dont see a restriction for certain attack types in this question...

Comment: @henchman: you are right, so i extended my answer a little bit

Comment: But by definition the length wouldn't be changed by the prepared statement (or it'd get slightly longer).  So if there is a security problem with excess length, this wouldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Well always check all input parameters. Also for length. If you don't trust it, block the whole IP. I had 100+ attacks like this today, but due to an extensive table with "bad words" I survived. If string ontains any bad word->block whole IP.

Comment: What do you mean by "bad words"?   Either you are properly handling SQL injection and preventing them in totality, or you have broken code.